# How to cache personalized news feed to minimize database read query?

Tags: php, database, caching, redis, memcached

Each user would be following different networks. The news feed consists of posts from different networks sorted according to rating. How can I design an effective cache system to minimize database read requests using memcached or any another software?
Website uses PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Databases are excellent at caching their working data sets. They're also excellent at serving many `SELECT` requests. Why don't you profile whether your database can take the load before attempting your own solution? What many people don't know is that implementing some sort of in-memory (memcached and similar) is actually somewhat slower than letting the db do the work. PHP is able to avoid the overhead of establishing frequent db connections, and MySQL's InnoDB is much quicker than memcached itself. Bottom line: measure before "optimizing".

Answer (score 0):

A database read it's not really slow if you have constraints on the tables, but if you looking for minimize the database requests, 'caching' in database is not a solution (because you don't want other request).
I would like to suggest the use of [Redis](http://redis.io/)